# Outputting pyspark dataframe in capnp (cap'n proto) format

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, capnproto

I have been tasked with outputting a Pyspark Dataframe into cap'n proto (.capnp) format.  Does anyone have a suggestion for the best way to do this?

I have a capnp schema, and I have seen the python wrapper for capnp (http://capnproto.github.io/pycapnp/), but I'm still not sure what's the best way to go from dataframe to capnp.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to go to RDD, the use `mapPartitions` to collect partitions as serialized [byte arrays](http://capnproto.github.io/pycapnp/quickstart.html#byte-strings-buffers) and join them in `collect()` or use `toLocalIterator` with saving to disk, if dataframe is big. See example pseudocode:

```
create = your_serialization_method
serialize_partition = lambda partition: [b''.join([create(object).to_bytes() for object in partition])] # creates one-element partition
output = b''.join(df.rdd.mapPartitions(serialize_partition).collect())
```